# Opening a link onclick html

Tags: html, button

So, i am creating this webpage, that opens another page in the same directory on the click of a button.
While doing so, I observed something which I couldn't find an satisfactory explanation to.
The button code I am using is this

```
<a class="class1" href="webpage2.html"><button type="button">Button1</button></a>
```

this seems to work, but not this,

```
<button type="button"><a class="class1" href="webpage2.html">Button1</a></button>
```

Why is this so? (Am I missing something very simple?)

Comment: Why are you stressing out using two tags. Why don't you try using only anchor tag. But you can apply button classes to it.
<a href="yousite.html" class="btn btn-primary">

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin your link solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a class="class1" href="webpage2.html"><button type="button">Button1</button></a>
```

and

```
<button type="button"><a class="class1" href="webpage2.html">Button1</a></button>
```

are different as one is a `button` inside an anchor tag...which means that, it is the anchor that gets clicked instead of the button, whereas, the second one, 
is an anchor tag inside the `button`.

In the first case, it is the click event of the anchor tag that gets worked instead of the button. In the second case, it is the click action of the button that is working and not the click action of the anchor tag. Thus, the `href` to `webpage2.html` doesnt work.

Comment: Yeah u r right, it seems that It is not allowed by html5 to have interactive elements as decendants.